# How to get list size in Data template selector of Bindable layout in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to show different data template based on itemSource size of the bindable layout. I tried using DataTemplateSelector but I can't access the parent list size. How to get the size in the DataTemplateSelector.

```
<StackLayout
                                x:Name="dynamicStack"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource brandMultipleTemplate}"
                                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryBrand}"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                Spacing="0"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

<ContentPage.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleBrandTemplate" />

            <DataTemplate x:Key="TwoBrandTemplate">

                <AbsoluteLayout
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <ffi:CachedImage
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                        Source="{Binding BrandLogo}" />

                </AbsoluteLayout>

            </DataTemplate>

            <selector:CategoryBrandTemplateSelector
                x:Key="brandMultipleTemplate"
                SingleBrand="{StaticResource SingleBrandTemplate}"
                TwoBrand="{StaticResource TwoBrandTemplate}" />

        </ResourceDictionary>

    </ContentPage.Resources>

class CategoryBrandTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate SingleBrand { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TwoBrand { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate FourBrand { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate MultiPageBrand { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var list = (List<CategoryBrand>)container.GetValue;

            if(list.Count == 4)
            {
                return FourBrand;
            } else if(list.Count == 2)
            {
                return TwoBrand;
            } else if(list.Count > 4)
            {
                return MultiPageBrand;
            } else
            {
                return SingleBrand;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the selector, the system throwing unable to cast to List exception.

Answer (score 1):

Typecast Container to ListView and from ListView get ItemSource in CategoryBrandTemplateSelector.

```
protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
{
  var listView = container as ListView;
  var list = listView?.ItemsSource as List<CategoryBrand>;
  var count = list?.Count;
  //....
}
```

[Reference code for DataTemplateSelector](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Templates/DataTemplateSelector)